# Assign selected range to two-dimentional array and compare 2 arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I'm stuck for hours solving my case. Code included below, I'll explain my case first for better understanding and to be easier to follow.

I have created a two dimensional array that has multiple compounds and corresponding heating values for them at two temperatures- it is contained in code and the user does not have a view of it.

The user types in the compounds and percentages of the mixture into the cells, and I want the selected cells that make up the array of multiple rows and two columns to be added to the two-dimensional array and then used in the function created to calculate a certain value (which is shown in the attached screenshot).

Ultimately, I want the program to search the user's entered and selected table to match the union name with the array, which is "hidden "in the code to properly perform the algebraic operation.

**Code**:

```
Function LoopThroughArray(T, x)
   Dim arr() As Variant
   ReDim arr(2, 4)

  arr(0, 0) = "CH4"
  arr(0, 1) = 35.818
  arr(0, 2) = 35.808

  arr(1, 0) = "C2H6"
  arr(1, 1) = 63.76
  arr(1, 2) = 63.74
  
  arr(2, 0) = "C3H8"
  arr(2, 1) = 91.18
  arr(2, 2) = 91.15

 Dim arrUser() As Variant
   ReDim arrUser(2, 4)

  arrUser(0, 0) = "CH4"
  arrUser(0, 1) = 0.7

  arrUser(1, 0) = "C2H6"
  arrUser(1, 1) = 0.3

   
'declare variables for the loop
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

'loop for the first dimension
   For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
   
'loop for the second dimension
      For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
      
         If T = 0 And arr(i, j) = "CH4" And arrUser(i, j) = "CH4" Then
         LoopThroughArray = arr(i, j + 1) * x 'the X is concentration of CH4 selected by user
         Else
         If T = 25 And arr(i, j) = "CH4" And arrUser(i, j) = "CH4" Then
         LoopThroughArray = arr(i, j + 2) * x 'the X is concentration of CH4 selected by user
         End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Function
```

**Screenshot from Excel:**
I am also attaching a screenshot showing the values of the table that is embedded in the code, and how the function would ultimately work.

[image: Example in excel]

**Problem:**

Currently, my code that I have written only works when the function is for a CH4 compound and the user manually select cell containing value of concentration (x in my code).

How should I modify the code so that the function/loop will search the table entered by the user, match the compound names from it with those in the built-in table in the code and calculate a value in the form: concentration (user defined, currently the x value in my code) * LHV for specific compound in desired temperatures (0 or 25 deg).

---

**1. Edit:**
What would I need to change to make the function independent of whether compounds/concentrations are entered not in columns but in rows?

---

**2. Edit:**

I changed the code a bit, where in the built-in array for compounds, the values are calculated by a polynomial that takes the temperature "T" set in the function.

a. I have created "if" conditions that inform about incorrectly entered data. I used WorksheetFunction.[...] for this (I wonder if using this option is the correct approach to the problem). When I use the function even in another worksheet, one message activates the messages from the other cells when they meet the conditions. Even when I launch the excel file the message pops up.
**Question 1: how should I change the code below so that the message pops up only once, when the formula is entered (when the assumed condition is met)?**

b. **Question 2: how to create conditions that:**

-when the temperature entered in the function is below 25 degrees for the selected compounds, a message will pop up to inform you of this (this applies to all compounds, including air),

-when the temperature entered in the function will be above 2200 degrees for the selected compounds where air will be, a message will appear informing that the temperature for air is out of range,

-if the temperature entered in the function is above 3000 degrees for the selected compounds, a message appears, informing that the temperature is out of range.

Example:
[image: Warnings]

Code:

```
Public Function Cp_mix_t(T, compounds As Range, concentrations As Range) As Double
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim curRow As Range
    Dim ret As Double, x As Double
    TN=273
    'Array of compounds and polynomials defining Cp
    ReDim arr(29, 2)
    arr(0, 0) = "CH4"
    arr(0, 1) = -1.9E-14 * (T + TN) ^ 5 + 2.1E-10 * (T + TN) ^ 4 - 7.1E-07 * (T + TN) ^ 3 + 7.8E-04 * (T + TN) ^ 2 + 1.4 * (T + TN) ^ 1 + 1709.8
    arr(20, 0) = "N2"
    arr(20, 1) = -3.5E-15 * (T + TN) ^ 5 + 3.9E-11 * (T + TN) ^ 4 - 1.61E-07 * (T + TN) ^ 3 + 2.87E-04 * (T + TN) ^ 2 - 0.17 * (T + TN) ^ 1 + 1054.5
    arr(28, 0) = "AIR"
    arr(28, 1) = -9.8E-15 * (T + TN) ^ 5 + 8.4E-11 * (T + TN) ^ 4 - 2.7E-07 * (T + TN) ^ 3 + 4.1E-04 * (T + TN) ^ 2 - 0.16 * (T + TN) ^ 1 + 1027.9

     
        concentrationHasRows = True
    If concentrations.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        concentrationHasRows = False
    End If
       
    For Each Cell In concentrations 'It checks if negative values of percentages in selected cells have been entered. If so, a warning appears and the program does not count Cp - it gives a value of 0
        If Cell.Value < 0 Then
        MsgBox ("A negative value was entered!")
        Cp_mix_t = 0
        Exit Function
     End If
    Next Cell

    If compounds.Count <> concentrations.Count Then 'It checks if the number of entered compounds matches the number of entered percentages. If not, a message appears and the program does not count Cp - it gives a value of 0
        MsgBox ("Wrong selection! Check the selected range of compounds/percentages.")
        Cp_mix_t = 0
        Exit Function
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Sum(concentrations) > 1 Then 'It checks if the sum of percentages >100%. If so, a warning appears and the program does not count Cp - it gives a value of 0
        MsgBox ("Sum of percentages greater than 100%!")
        Cp_mix_t = 0
        Exit Function
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Sum(concentrations) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.Sum(concentrations) < 1 Then 'It checks if the sum of the percentages =100%. If yes, then only the message
        MsgBox ("The sum of the percentages is not equal to 100%!")
    End If
    
    ' Loop through user input rows:
k = 1
    For Each m In compounds
        arraycompound = Trim(UCase(m.Value2))
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 0) = arraycompound Then
                ' x retrieves user's input of concentration:
                If concentrationHasRows Then
                    x = concentrations.Cells(k, 1).Value2
                Else
                    x = concentrations.Cells(1, k).Value2
                End If
                If T < 25 Then
                    MsgBox ("Temperature below 25 deg")
                ElseIf T > 2200 And arr(i, 0) = "AIR" Then
                MsgBox ("Temperature for air above 2200 deg ")
'                ElseIf T > 3000 And arr(i, 0) = Not "AIR" Then
'                MsgBox ("Temperature for compounds above 3000 deg")
                End If
                ret = ret + arr(i, j + 1) * x
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        k = k + 1
   Next
   Cp_mix_t = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Re-edited)
I have found this possible solution. The code in Data module would be:

```
    ' call the function like in  =LHV(25;A9:B10;E5:E6)
Function LHV(T, compounds As Range, concentrations As Range) As Double
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    If ThisWorkbook.done = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.numMsg = 0
        ThisWorkbook.done = True
        For Each cell In compounds.Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            If cell.HasFormula Then
    ' change down here "LHV(" by your formula's name:
                  If InStr(Replace(UCase(cell.Formula), " ", ""), "LHV(") Then
                    v = Split(cell.Formula, ",") ' code arrives here?
                    pos = InStr(v(0), "(")
                    v(0) = Mid(v(0), pos + 1)
                    Set rng1 = Range(v(1))
                    v(2) = Replace(v(2), ")", "")
                    Set rng2 = Range(v(2))
                    cellLHV v(0), rng1, rng2
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Temperature below 25 deg")
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 2 Then
        MsgBox ("Temperature for air above 2200 deg ")
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 4 Then
    '  MsgBox ("Temperature for compounds above 3000 deg")
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 8 Then
    '  MsgBox ("Some other message")
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.numMsg = 0
    LHV = cellLHV(T, compounds, concentrations)
    ThisWorkbook.done = False
End Function


Function cellLHV(T, compounds As Range, concentrations As Range) As Double
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim curRow As Range
    Dim ret As Double, x As Double
    ReDim arr(2, 4)
    arr(0, 0) = "CH4"
    arr(0, 1) = 35.818
    arr(0, 2) = 35.808
    arr(1, 0) = "C2H6"
    arr(1, 1) = 63.76
    arr(1, 2) = 63.74
    arr(2, 0) = "C3H8"
    arr(2, 1) = 91.18
    arr(2, 2) = 91.15
    
    concentrationHasRows = True
    If concentrations.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        concentrationHasRows = False
    End If
    ' Loop through user input rows:
    k = 1
    For Each m In compounds
        arraycompound = Trim(UCase(m.Value2))
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 0) = arraycompound Then
                ' x retrieves user's input of concentration:
                If concentrationHasRows Then
                    x = concentrations.Cells(k, 1).Value2
                Else
                    x = concentrations.Cells(1, k).Value2
                End If
                If T < 25 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.numMsg = ThisWorkbook.numMsg Or 1
                ElseIf T > 2200 And arr(i, 0) = "AIR" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.numMsg = ThisWorkbook.numMsg Or 2
                'ElseIf T > 3000 And arr(i, 0) = Not "AIR" Then
                 'ThisWorkbook.numMsg = ThisWorkbook.numMsg Or 4
                 ' ElseIf ..... then
                 'ThisWorkbook.numMsg = ThisWorkbook.numMsg Or 8
                End If
                ret = ret + arr(i, j + 1) * x
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        k = k + 1
    Next
    cellLHV = ret
End Function
```

...and the code from Data's ThisWorkbook:

```
    Public numMsg As Long
Public done As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ThisWorkbook.done = False
End Sub
```

Also converting arr() into a global Public variable speed can be improved.

If temperature T is going to be a cell range then change the function into:

```
Public Function Cp_mix_t(T, compounds As Range, concentrations As Range) As Double
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim rng0 As Range
If ThisWorkbook.done = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.numMsg = 0
    ThisWorkbook.done = True
    For Each cell In compounds.Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.HasFormula Then
              If InStr(Replace(cell.Formula, " ", ""), "Cp_mix_t(") Then
                v = Split(cell.Formula, ",")
                pos = InStr(v(0), "(")
                v(0) = Mid(v(0), pos + 1)
                Set rng0 = Range(v(0))
                Set rng1 = Range(v(1))
                v(2) = Replace(v(2), ")", "")
                Set rng2 = Range(v(2))
                ' code arrives here ?
                cellCp_mix_t rng0, rng1, rng2
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Temperature below 25 deg")
End If
If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 2 Then
    MsgBox ("Temperature for air above 2200 deg ")
End If
If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 4 Then
'  MsgBox ("Temperature for compounds above 3000 deg")
End If
If ThisWorkbook.numMsg And 8 Then
'  MsgBox ("Some other message")
End If

  ThisWorkbook.numMsg = 0
  Cp_mix_t = cellCp_mix_t(T, compounds, concentrations)
  ThisWorkbook.done = False
End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242941/discussion-on-answer-by-xavier-junque-assign-selected-range-to-two-dimentional-a).